# ‘We just need your umbrella’, what does it mean?

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context

I am watching the video on youtube: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Vuk1EhkEctE. It is about the israeli lobby in britain.

What does the israeli political officer mean by 'we just need your umbrella'?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

An umbrella in literal aspect means a tool which protects someone from something (which I think, you know).

In that context the political officer is asking for cover, in case any risk may arise.

Answer (score 0):

*Umbrella* is used metaphorically.
So, "we just need your **umbrella**", here means "we just need your **protection**".

***Umbrella*** — [ODO](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/umbrella)

> a protecting force or influence.
>   *"Europe sought a measure of independence from the US defence umbrella"*

Comment: I am quite mystified as to why this answer is attracting DVs, and the other a +1...

Comment: @Cascabel I'm getting downvotes on random answers. I presume it's from some users who are upset because of me reviewing their posts.

Comment: Yeah, I think the same was happening to me, yesterday. There has been a lot of childish behaviour recently, possibly from actual children. Witness all the "pooh" edits.